# Javascript to allow only certain characters?

Tags: javascript, validation

I have a text-box into which a user can input a comment. The comment could be a combination of alphabets ( lowercase or uppercase) or digits or @ or semi-colon or colon or period or comma or $ or forward slash or space or - or _. I have tried using the following function but it does not test for $ or space or - or _. How can I include these also in this JavaScript function? I also want to allow an empty string in input.

```
function alphanumeric(inputtxt) 
{  
  var letters = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/; 
  if(inputtxt.value.match(letters)) 
  { 
    alert('Your registration number have accepted : you can try another'); 
    document.form1.text1.focus(); 
    return true; 
  } 
  else 
  { 
    alert('Please input alphanumeric characters only'); 
    return false; 
  } 
}
```

**ANSWER** is as below ( provided with the help of xdazz):

```
   function alphanumeric(inputtxt) 
{  
  var letters = /^[\w\d\s@;:.,-/$/]*$/; 
  if(inputtxt.value.match(letters)) 
  { 
    alert('Your registration number have accepted : you can try another'); 
    document.form1.text1.focus(); 
    return true; 
  } 
  else 
  { 
    alert('Please input alphanumeric characters only'); 
    return false; 
  } 
}
```

Comment: You don't appear to have even tried to allow those symbols...

Comment: I tried @ or semi-colon or colon or period or comma, and they do work, but when I include $ it throws a javascript error.

Comment: What is the error? What input causes the error? Don't *describe* the input; *show* the input.

Comment: Try this: `/^[\s\d\w;,@-_./]+$/`

Comment: Kolink : Here's the link that shows you the error.http://screencast.com/t/fydGWq5wY9f. Why would I post my question if there was no problem I faced ????

Comment: Ecko : I used your expression but it doesn't accept  $ or -. It accepts underscore though. It also doesn't accept an empty string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the regex below.

```
var letters = /^[\w\d\s$@;.,-/]+$/;
```

Comment: @Kolink `"-".match(letters)` gives you `["-"]`.

Comment: @xdazz -  Your expression doesn't accept $ symbol or an empty string.

Comment: @Sunil Just need to add `$` into this regex, and if you let `''` more match, change `+` to `*`, `+` means at least one of these chars.

Comment: @xdazz - I appreciate your help and guidance on this. As per your advice, I used with success the following expression: var letters = /^[\w\d\s@;:.,-/$/]*$/;

Comment: Doesn't a hyphen within square brackets need to be either first, last or escaped? Because it _does_ have special meaning within square brackets...